# Codenameone - when cursor is focused on Text field with keyboard is on, will distort the screen

Tags: codenameone

When entering data in text field on IOS in portrait mode with keyboard on, if device is flipped to landscape mode this will distort the content in the form and screen will split vertically into two halves. This will make the content display distorted fashion. If the screen is flipped when not entering data in text field will will work without any issues.Please advise.

Comment: This sounds like a regression with iOS input, please file an issue here: http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new make sure to specify the exact device model & exact OS version. If you used any special iOS build hints please mention that too

Comment: This is now fixed in Git.  It will be available in the next server update.

Comment: Thank You Shai and Steve. When would the next server update? Thx.

Comment: Hi Shai/Steve, can you please let me know when would be the next server update with this fix? Thx