# Picker not showing at the right moment

Tags: codenameone

I am experiencing some weird behavior with the pickers in my app since the pixel perfect picker update : The picker is showing when the form is called to be show, so before the form is showing.

I've tried with the new lightweight mode, with the old mode, inside a PickerComponent, with just a picker, on Android 7, iOS 10 and the simulator, all have a similar behavior.

The only difference is that with a PickerComponent, the bug appear when the Form is shown a second time.

The bug occur once, because I keep my forms in memory most of the time and it occur only the first time.

Here is a little code sample to add in the start method of the barebone hello world :

```
Picker pick = new Picker();
pick.setType(PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
pick.setStrings("First model", "Second model", "Third model");
pick.addActionListener(e->Dialog.show("Picker result", pick.getSelectedString(), "OK", null));
pick.setUseLightweightPopup(false);

Picker pick2 = new Picker();
pick2.setType(PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
pick2.setStrings("First model", "Second model", "Third model");
pick2.addActionListener(e->Dialog.show("Picker result", pick2.getSelectedString(), "OK", null));
pick2.setUseLightweightPopup(true);

PickerComponent pickerComponent = PickerComponent.createStrings("First model", "Second model", "Third model").label("Model Heavy");
pickerComponent.getPicker().setUseLightweightPopup(false);
pickerComponent.getPicker().addActionListener(e->Dialog.show("Picker result", pickerComponent.getPicker().getSelectedString(), "OK", null));

PickerComponent pickerComponent2 = PickerComponent.createStrings("First model", "Second model", "Third model").label("Model Light");
pickerComponent2.getPicker().setUseLightweightPopup(true);
pickerComponent2.getPicker().addActionListener(e->Dialog.show("Picker result", pickerComponent2.getPicker().getSelectedString(), "OK", null));

Form hi = new Form("PickerCompo Heavy", BoxLayout.y());
hi.add(pickerComponent);

Form hi2 = new Form("PickerCompo Light", BoxLayout.y());
hi2.add(pickerComponent2);

Form hi3 = new Form("Picker Heavy", BoxLayout.y());
hi3.add(pick);

Form hi4 = new Form("Picker Light", BoxLayout.y());
hi4.add(pick2);

Form caller = new Form("Call Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
Button callForm = new Button("hit me heavyweight Compo");
callForm.addActionListener(e->{
    hi.setBackCommand("Back", null, ev-> caller.showBack());
    hi.show();
});

Button callFormLight = new Button("hit me Lightweight Compo");
callFormLight.addActionListener(e->{
    hi2.setBackCommand("Back", null, ev-> caller.showBack());
    hi2.show();
});

Button callForm3 = new Button("hit me heavyweight");
callForm3.addActionListener(e->{
    hi3.setBackCommand("Back", null, ev-> caller.showBack());
    hi3.show();
});

Button callForm4 = new Button("hit me Lightweight");
callForm4.addActionListener(e->{
    hi4.setBackCommand("Back", null, ev-> caller.showBack());
    hi4.show();
});

caller.add(callForm);
caller.add(callFormLight);
caller.add(callForm3);
caller.add(callForm4);
caller.show();
```

Any idea of a workaround ? I'm using them on some major forms in my app, and I'd like to update the app to resolve the distorting screen on iOS (SO : [Distorted screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50263036/codenameone-when-cursor-is-focused-on-text-field-with-keyboard-is-on-will-dis) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a regression with `Picker` due to changes in the [focus functionality](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/right-sidemenu-tab-order.html) that were used with the `Picker` change but are applicable even in the native functionality.

This should be fixed in the update that we pushed out just now.

Comment: I've just tried it on iOS and Android, working fine again. Thanks for the update